# How to invoke different methods in sub-classes with different parameters by calling a single method in super class object without using if condition?

Tags: java, oop, if-statement, inheritance, abstract-class

I have a `Vehicle` abstract class and two subclasses `Bike` and `Car`, which has 1 common method and 2 different methods. I want to execute all methods from my main class method by invoking only a single method on the input object.

```java
abstract class Vehicle {
  
  Tire tire;
  
  // a common method
  void checkTire (TireValidator tireValidator) {
    tireValidator.check(tire);
  }

  // How to design this abstract method to invoke all validations
  abstract void runAllValidations();
}
```

Now `Bike` class has to check brakes in addition to tire

```java
class Bike extends vehicle {
  
  Brakes brakes;
  
  void checkBrakes (BrakeValidator brakeValidator) {
    brakeValidator.check(brakes);
  }

  // How to override runAllValidations method here?
  
}
```

`Car` class has to check gas in addition to tire

```java
class Car extends vehicle {
  
  Gas gas;
  
  void checkGas (GasValidator gasValidator) {
    gasValidator.check(gas);
  }

  // How to override runAllValidations method here?
  
}
```

How can I design my `runAllValidations` method and override it in my subclasses so that both the checks - tire & brakes for bike, and tire & gas for car, will run **WITHOUT using any if conditions? **

```java
void main() {
  
  TireValidator TireValidator;
  
  BrakeValidator brakeValidator;

  GasValidator gasValidator;


  Vehicle car = new car(...);

  vehicle bike = new Bike(...);

  
  // how to call runAllValidations method? What to pass as parameters?
  car.runAllValidations(...);
  bike.runAllValidations(...);
  
}
```

## First way (but with unnecessary parameters)

One way to do this design my abstract method to accept all three validators as parameters.

Vehicle:

```java
abstract void runAllValidations(TireValidator TireValidator, BrakeValidator brakeValidator, GasValidator gasValidator);
```

Bike:

```java
void runAllValidations(TireValidator tireValidator, BrakeValidator brakeValidator, GasValidator gasValidator) {
  
  checkTire(tireValidator);
  
  checkBrakes(brakeValidator);

}
```

Car:

```java
void runAllValidations(TireValidator tireValidator, BrakeValidator brakeValidator, GasValidator gasValidator) {
  
  checkTire(tireValidator);
  
  checkGas(GasValidator);

}
```

Here, the biggest problem is that I'm passing unnecessary validators to these methods.

## Second way (but we are using if conditions)

```java
void main() {}

void checkAllvalidationsForVehicle(Vehicle v) {
  
  if (v instanceof Bike) {
    Bike b = (Bike) v;

    b.checkTire(tireValidator);
    b.checkBrakes(brakeValidator);

  } else if (v instanceof Car) {
    Car c = (Car) v;

    c.checkTire(tireValidator);
    c.checkGas(gasValidator);

  }

}
```

Here there are if - else conditions, which I'm trying to avoid in my code.

**What is the best possible way to solve these issues?**

Comment: Some questions: (1) Is the hierarchy of `Vehicle` - `Car` - `Bike` important, or are you using the base class just to share some methods? If you only want to share some methods, you could use composition instead of inheritance, and *maybe* make the problem easier. (1a) If the inheritance is important, are you going to have deeper inheritance (e.g. Taxi extends Car extends Vehicle), or is it going to stay 1 level deep forever? (2) How many entities do you anticipate to have? Will this number change frequently? (I am asking because this could be a candidate for applying the visitor pattern)

Comment: Also: (3) Are validators fixed for the entire hierarchy or could they change? E.g. different validator for different business cases or for different entities.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos
(1) Currently there are 3 subclasses such as `Car` and `Bike` and may increase upto 5. (1a) Currently only one level deep `Car`. In six months, more fields may have to be added to `Car`. So at that point, I am planning to extend it to `Taxi` following open/closed principle. In another six months might be extended to `Uber`. So 4 levels deep in the future. 

(2) What do you mean by entities? `car`, `Bike` etc? More may more in the future.

(3) Validators are very diverse; both number of validators and implementations vary widely.

Answer (score 0):

If you just have a variable of type `Vehicle`, you cannot know what kind of validation it needs except by checking what type it actually stores. If you *do* know what validations the vehicle needs for whatever reason, then you don't need the abstract method in `Vehicle` - create an interface for each kind of validation, like `BrakeAndTireValidatable` and `GasAndTireValidatable`, and cast to the appropriate interface.

So how about assigning the validators to the vehicles when you *do* know the type? The classes would have validator fields, and `runAllValidations` would be parameterless.

```
abstract class Vehicle {
  
  private Tire tire;
  private TireValidator tireValidator;
  
  public void checkTire() {
    tireValidator.check(tire);
  }

  public void setTireValidator(TireValidator tireValidator) {
    this.tireValidator = tireValidator;
  }

  public abstract void runAllValidations();
}

class Bike extends vehicle {
  
  private Brakes brakes;
  private BrakeValidator;
  
  void checkBrakes() {
    brakeValidator.check(brakes);
  }

  public void setBrakeValidator(BrakeValidator brakeValidator) {
    this.brakeValidator = brakeValidator;
  }
  
  @Override
  public void runAllValidations() {
     checkTire();
     checkBrakes();
  }
}

class Car extends vehicle {
  
  private Gas brakes;
  private GasValidator;
  
  void checkGas() {
    gasValidator.check(gas);
  }

  public void setGasValidator(GasValidator gasValidator) {
    this.gasValidator = gasValidator;
  }
  
  @Override
  public void runAllValidations() {
     checkTire();
     checkGas();
  }
}
```

Then in `main`, you can do:

```
TireValidator tireValidator = ...;
BrakeValidator brakeValidator = ...;
GasValidator gasValidator = ...;

Car car = new Car(...);
Bike bike = new Bike(...);
car.setTireValidator(tireValidator);
bike.setTireValidator(tireValidator);
car.setGasValidator(gasValidator);
bike.setBrakeValidator(brakeValidator);

// it is still possible to put car and bike into "Vehicle"-typed variables
// and call runAllValidations
// here I'll demonstrate this by putting them in a list and iterate over the list
List.of(car, bike).forEach(Vehicle::runAllValidations);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't completely solve the problem. We don't have `Car car = new Car(...)`, but we have `Vehicle car = new Car(...)` and Similarly `Bike`. 

So you don't know whether to call `setGasValidator` or `setBrakeValidator` unless you use an if-else as described in *Second Way*.

Comment: @Pardhu What I meant was that you should set the validators when the types of the vehicles are still known, before they are put into a `Vehicle` variable. Otherwise, how do you know whether the validators that you are trying to use are appropriate for some random `Vehicle`?